# Is there another way to make an object go up and down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a character that goes up and down. Whenever i start the game it goes oblique.

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1), transform.position.x, transform.position.z);
}
```

As my codes says i want it to go up, but I must have made a mistake in the code. Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Hard to say without more code. It will depend on how you've set up your camera. But, it looks like you are probably just modifying the wrong coordinate in your position.

Comment: Sorry i switched my x and y axis. I have edited it now as i wrote it. Still not going up at y.

Comment: Are you sure you edited it?  Cuz it still shows x as being the second parameter, or is that intentional?